# Clear spreadsheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How do I clear the sheet with PHPExcel? Something like Sheet.ClearContents in VBA.
All I could find was delete rows and columns and it's not useful for me as I need to clear entire sheet before writing data to the file.

Comment: Explain `it's not working for me`.... but there is no built-in method that will remove all cell data from a sheet, and (perhaps surprisingly) nobody has ever asked for it before

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove the sheets and create a new one.

```
$myExcelObj->disconnectWorksheets();
$myExcelObj->createSheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

not a good way, you will erase the style . 
you should copy the style first!额